# java.lang.NumberFormatException in scala

Tags: scala

I am using Scala and I catch this exception when trying to execute this code:

```
ipv4("63".toByte, "173".toByte, "67".toByte, "135".toByte)

def ipv4(a: Byte, b: Byte, c: Byte, d: Byte): Integer = {
    return a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d;
  }
```

Exception:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"173" Radix:10
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"173" Radix:10
        at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:151)
        at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:175)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toByte(StringLike.scala:264)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toByte(StringOps.scala:30)
        at Runner$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Runner.scala:27)
        at Runner$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Runner.scala:23)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at Runner$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Runner.scala:23)
        at Runner$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Runner.scala:21)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at Runner$.main(Runner.scala:21)
        at Runner.main(Runner.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Byte` is an 8-bit signed number. It can contain values between -128 and 127. The value 173 is outside the range of numbers that can be stored in a `Byte`, therefore you get an exception. Note that the error message is telling you exactly this ("Value out of range").

What you can do is parse it as an `Int` and then convert that to a `Byte`:

```
"173".toInt.toByte
```

The conversion from `Int` to `Byte` will simply cut off the top 24 bits of the `Int`. You'll end up with a `Byte` with the value -83.

Answer (score 1):

The range of a signed Byte is from -128 to 127.

Answer (score 1):

`"173"` is out of range:

```
"173".toByte //=> NumberFormatException
"127".toByte //=> 127
"-128".toByte //=> -128
```